# Add password to zip file PHP

Tags: php, passwords, compression, zip

Is it possible to compress a file in php and then add password to protect it?
It is easy to zip files, but I can't find a way to add password.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible when you have installed the zip programm on your linux machine. Then you can run the zip command over [`system`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.system.php).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to "compress a file in php that is password protected", if you meant in that order.  You won't be able to get any compression on something that is encrypted.  Encrypted data will appear random, and is therefore incompressible.  You need to compress the data *before* encryption.

If you want to encrypt entries in zip file, there are two ways that the format supports that.  The first uses the original zip "encryption" which has been shown to be quite poor, and should never be used.  Later updates to the zip format permit proper encryption, such as AES, but you would likely have to purchase a program to support that.

I would recommend instead using a standard encryption utility (executed with system() as suggested) to encrypt the entire .zip file.  You can use crypt or gpg.